# Kusto query-ingest for multiple tables in one command

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, kql, azure-data-explorer

in the Pipeline Expression builder I want to run one command to ingest data into different tables. How is that possible? Below would be two commands who would work on its own, but I want to combine them and run them in one command:

```
.set table_1 with (extend_schema=true) <|
let output_1 = function_1;
output_1
.set table_2 with (extend_schema=true) <|
let output_2 = function_2;
output_2
```

Output_1 would be assigned to table_1 and output_2 would be assigned to table_2

Answer (score 0):

There is an Azure DevOps extension provided by Microsoft: [**Azure Data Explorer - Pipeline Tools**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Azure-Kusto.PublishToADX).

This extension provides the pipelines tasks to integrate Azure DevOps Pipelines with Azure Data Explorer and run the Kusto queries.

you can install this extension to your Azure DevOps organization, and then try the provided tasks in your pipeline.

Also reference the docs "[**Azure DevOps Task for Azure Data Explorer**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/devops)".

Answer (score 0):

In KQL is an execute database script command. It executes a batch of management commands in the scope of a single database. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/execute-database-script